# Can't dismiss NSAlert in Qt app

Tags: cocoa, qt, macos, events

I'm trying to display an NSAlert in a Qt application. The alert is shown using runModal, in response to some logic that's triggered by a QTimerEvent, so the stack looks like this:

```
[NSAlert runModal]
<.......>
timerEvent(QTimerEvent*)
<.......>
QCoreApplication::exec()
```

However, the alert cannot be dismissed. The buttons respond to clicks or key shortcuts, but it is never dismissed. I'm guessing it's some kind of run loop problem: the NSAlert is blocking somehow?

I can display NSAlert elsewhere in the app without problems. If I substitute a QMessageBox it works as expected. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: any special reason you aren't using a QDialog?

Comment: Appearance and behaviour. QtMessageBox looks nothing like the native alert dialogs on OS X. See http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-9481

Comment: Same problem in 2018, Qt 5.12